# Python connection to a Hortonworks Ambari (Hive).

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to connect my local Python interface to connect with a web based Hortonworks Ambari client. The idea is to write python scripts that could talk to the Hive databases and return results on my local machine (python). I have read a lot about this on the web and unfortunately with no luck. I am hoping if someone could share a complete script that could help me. Also - please elaborate on what the host must be, the user name and password given some of this is getting very very confusing. Thank you.

Comment: What does Ambari have to do with that? There are ODBC / JDBC drivers for Hive, and even a "native" Python client, courtesy of Cloudera > https://github.com/cloudera/impyla

Comment: Yes. I tried this but it keeps coming back as "HiveServer2Error: Failed after retrying 3 times". This is a very short piece of script but not sure what is going wrong.                                                                                                       from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect(host='telewfiqaihon01.tlo2qa.local', port=10000)
cursor = conn.cursor()

Answer (score 0):

Try, something like this, this works for a Hortonworks Cluster. This pseudo code is from a python script and has some commonly used operations which might come handy :

```
import pyhs2
conn = pyhs2.connect(
host=<Server that hosts HIVE, ambari HOSTS view should help identify>,
port=<10000 is default>, 
authMechanism="PLAIN",
user=<user or default user "hive">,
password=<Password for user >,
database=<dbname>)
cur = conn.cursor()

query = "select 1 from dbname.table where col="+"'"+<value>+"'"

print ("query= "+query)
cur.execute(query)
SomeValue= cur.fetch()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Some of the details can be found from hive-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
<value> **10000** </value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://<**some server name**>/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>**hive**</value>
</property>
```

More information on phs2:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2#SettingUpHiveServer2-PythonClientDriver

Another resource would be:
[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-Python](http://HiveClient)

Comment: I tried this method earlier but for some reason unable to overcome "ImportError: No module named _saslwrapper" error. There is not much documenation around saslwrapper. I have pip installed sasl etc. but its not solving the issue.

Comment: @AyanCH .. would you be able to post you script, Error, Python Environment details (and if you have Single or Multi version) . HDP environment details.